# Hibernate/JPA incorrect join in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

See code below for my 2 entity classes - when I call the findAll() method from my OrigRepository class, it joins these two tables using both primary keys. I want the join to be between the primary key of the Orig table and the foreign key entry in the MsgResponse table ("OrigID") - any sugggestions?

**Orig Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "originator")
public class Orig {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "OrigID")
    private int OrigID;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "OrigID")  
    private MsgResponse responseInfo;
}
```

**MsgResponse Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message_response")
public class MsgResponse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int responseId;

    @Column(name = "OrigID")
    private int OrigId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="responseInfo")
    private Orig OrigInfo; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to see the jpa documentation 
[here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html).

Example 1 should be your case

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Tried following this and now the tables aren't joining at all. Do I need to configure the relationship somewhere else in my (Spring Boot) application?

Answer (score 0):

Try to swap relation ownership, that is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "originator")
public class Orig {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "OrigID")
    private int OrigID;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="origInfo") 
    private MsgResponse responseInfo;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "message_response")
public class MsgResponse {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int responseId;

    // @Column(name = "OrigID")
    // private int origId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "OrigID")  
    private Orig origInfo; 
}
```

Note that the `@JoinColum` annotation is in now in the MsgResponse entity. This is because in a `@OneToOne` the join column refers to the **source** entity (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name())).

Hope this could help.